# How to to measure when 2 functions are done one web page?

Tags: javascript, html

So i am writing a page with will measure load time of drawing the same thing but one in SVG and one in Canvas.

It draws squares in random positions and page loads after drawing both - svg taking more time. But both times are the same and it looks like its time from Canvas drawing. Method i use to see load time is simple a just take date from start of the function and from end. This way i know how much time it takes. But when i try the same trick on the other drawing it gives me same time - first one (Canvas)

What i do wrong?? Or maybe i cant do it on one page ??

My code that looks like this:

```
function draw(){
before = (new Date()).getTime();
//Draw Canvas
var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
for(var i=0;i<10000;i++){

    //code for drawing Canvas- works and is not important in this question

}

//load time  Canvas                 
var after = (new Date()).getTime(); 
var sec = (after-before)/1000; 
var renTime = document.getElementById("loadingtime"); 
renTime.innerHTML = "Figury Canvas rysowały się: " + sec + " sekund."; 

 // draw svg 

 beforeSVG = (new Date()).getTime();

for (var i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {

    //code for drawing SVG - works and is not important in this question

}

//load time SVG                 
 var afterSVG = (new Date()).getTime(); 
 var secSVG = (after-before)/1000; 
 var renTimeSVG = document.getElementById("loadingtimeSVG"); 
 renTimeSVG.innerHTML = "Figury rysowały się: " + secSVG + " sekund."; 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are still using the time from the canvas benchmark for your svg benchmark:

```
var secSVG = (after-before)/1000;
```

Aren't they supposed to be:

```
var secSVG = (afterSVG-beforeSVG)/1000;
```

Comment: God i am stupid. I looked nearly one hour on this code and didnt saw that. Thx mate i owe you a bear :D